# Population model and t representing years with a function $\sin t$ Should this t be in radians?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I just came out from Exam and got confused with one of the answer I wrote:

There is a polulation model $P$, population in 1000s, for $t$ representing years and $t \geq 0$

$$P=\dfrac {6}{1+e^{\frac 1 2 \sin {2t}}}$$

At $P = 3, T = 0$,
(I don't recall numbers here exactly. I only know $P = 3, T = 0$ for sure)

Find years it took when population reaches 4000.

So it did not tell whether $t$ should be in radians or degrees. 
Until today for all cases in modelling like this I thought you naturally use radians instead of degrees.

But what I got was $t \approx 0.41$ in rads and $27.1$ in degrees. 
So I chose 27.1 instead as it is indeed possible to model t as years in degrees and values seemed more "natural".

Is this correct? Question never stated whether it should be in rads or degs.

More and more I think as I write it down here makes me think I got this question wrong..

Comment: whenever combining *trig* and *calculus*, always use radians!

Comment: it would be hard to do calculus with argument for trig functions in degrees; for one you don't get the derivative of $\sin(t)$ to be $\cos t.$

Comment: $t$ should have units of time, and the "2" in front of the $t$ in the sine implicitly has units $rads/$time

Comment: @danimal I think so too.. damn it its too late :L

Comment: If I was marking this I would probably give you the marks... it is a good thing that you mistrusted your answer. My guess is that the answer is $\approx 0.41$ *of a year*.

Answer (score 0):

Without further information, like another data point I see no reason why you'd be wrong. You could even use grad, or mil as other measures of angle.

Mind, .41r ~ 23.5°, not 27.1°

Was that the complete question?

Comment: No that was last part of a bigger question.
I was supposed to derieve that formula P from a differential equation.

Comment: In which case, then as it's from a differential equation, it's probably most likely to be in radians, as discussed.